# How does SQL Server Database Project: Publish decide when to recreate a table?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have a SQL Server Database Project in which I've made several changes to the schema where I've changed column data types from `NUMERIC (18,0)` to `INT`. We're trying to normalize the data type used for Primary Keys, it's a currently 50/50 mix.

When I generate the Publish script, some of the tables are recreated in the script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmp_XYZ]
INSERT TABLE [dbo].[tmp_XYZ] SELECT ... FROM [dbo].[XYZ]
DROP TABLE [dbo].[XYZ]
sp_rename N'[dbo].[tmp_XYZ]', N'XYZ';
```

but other tables are just updated via `ALTER` statements

`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ABC] ALTER COLUMN [AbcID] INT NULL;`

Is there some rule that dictates when a table will be recreated, and when it's just altered in place ?

Comment: You can't change a column definition if it's part of a key/index. Dropping the keys, changing the definition and then rebuilding the keys will, in general, be more costly than just building the parallel structure with the new definition, then dropping the old and renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to Right Click on your object name and choose script  as ...
Then you have options to create or alter
If you couldn't find Alter ,you can go to design view, right click and choose Generate Change Script ... to find the alter statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an easy problem. It's the same problem as changing a table in the table designer. I think you've changed a column inside your table design which needs to drop and recreate the table to let the column order in the same position.

Here is a short example. Take this table design as given:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(
    id int identity(1,1), 
    firstname nvarchar(100), 
    name nvarchar(100), 
    street nvarchar(100)
)
```

This will create the columns in a specified order. You can see this order here:

```
SELECT name, column_id
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Test')
```

You'll see something like that:

```
column_name column_id
id          1
firstname   2
name        3
street      4
```

If you change the the column `name` via designer or in your case in the data project, this will cause SQL Server to obtain this order upright.
In this case you try to change the column `name` to `lastname`. This will enforce SQL Management Studio and other programs like that to keep the `column_id` upright. This can only be done, if the table is completely recreated with the right columnorder. SQL Server create a temporary table stub, insert everything into it, drop the old table and rename the temporary table to the old original name. Just as in your code above.

After that you'll see something like that:

```
column_name column_id
id          1
firstname   2
lastname    3
street      4
```

If you would simply rename the last column or do it manually, everything would be fine. Manually would be much more efficient, as there isn't the need to move ALL data to a new table. The manual way would be this:

```
-- Create the new column
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test ADD lastname nvarchar(100)
GO
-- Populate the new column using the old one
UPDATE dbo.Test
SET lastname = name 
GO
-- Drop the old column afterwards
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test DROP COLUMN name
```

This behavior will result in the following result:

```
column_name column_id
id          1
firstname   2
street      4
lastname    5
```

The last one will be much more efficient, as already stated.

Hopefully this will answer your question, even if the answer comes lately.